# How can I get the T95/FV4201 Chieftain?

Tags: world-of-tanks

There's this rare tank in the game, T95/FV4201 Chieftain, which I often hear of as a "overpowered reward tank". However, many people including me don't really know how this tank (and other similar reward tanks) are earned.

The little information that I know so far is that it's a reward for playing Clan wars, and is awarded only to the most exceptional players. So even though I probably won't be picking it up, lots of players don't know what they have to do to get this tank, as it isn't mentioned on the Wargaming wiki or forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you suspected, the answer involves being succesful at Clan Wars.

To be specific, the top x ranked players in the clan wars tournament (you farm something called fame points by taking part in and winning battles with your team)have the chance to buy this tank for 4000 bonds.
For everyone else, as long as you compete in at least 5 clanwars battles, you may enter an auction and place a bid of whatever amount of bonds you like in order to win one of a limited number of reward tanks (the pool is limited, and you may specify which tank you want)